# "Город над речкой" — правильно или нет?

Tags: стилистика

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильно ли пишут:

```
"город над рекой"
```

Если река пересекает часть территории города? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, тут все же правильно сказать "город НА реке". "Над" обычно употребляетя в том случае, когда город стоит на правом, высоком берегу реки.

Comment: А левые высокими не бывают? Или там городов не ставят принципиально?

Comment: А левые высокими не бывают?
В Северном полушарии - нет, исключения - уникальны, если, конечно, речь идёт о равнинных реках, в горах встречается всякое. Что касается городов, то Москва тоже стоит на левом берегу Москвы-реки.

"Город над вольной Невой" - историческая часть Петербурга 0 тоже на девом берегу Невы.

Answer (score 1):

"Город над вольной Невой" - историческая часть Петербурга - тоже на левом берегу Невы.

думаю, речь должна идти не о географии, а о стиле речи. В стихах, возвышенном стиле - вполне уместно. А вообще исторически, когда путешествовали в основном по рекам, города действительно воспринимались как стоящие **над** реками.